# Freestyle color from UV-mapped texture or vertex color?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, vertices, freestyle

I'd like to be able to precisely control the color of Freestyle rendered strokes, either by reading the coordinates of UV-mapped textures, or by reading vertex colors. I've been playing with the Freestyle color options but haven't found a recipe for either yet. Does anyone know of one?